# Laravel API: Get 500 (Internal Server Error) while trying to store datas using JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, post, laravel-8

I'm trying to send data from frontend to my Laravel API using AJAX jQuery but I get a http 500 error.

When I use Postman for testing, everything is OK, but when I do it from the browser, my server returns an error.

Here is the JavaScript code responsible for sending the data:

```
$("#saver").on("click", event => {
   $.ajax({
      data: Tasks,
      type: 'POST', // on précise la methode
      url: url_store, //l'url vers laquelle AJAX doit diriger la requette
     // async:false,
      // on success 
      success: function(response) { // si tout se passe bien NOTE: reponse contient la réponse obtenu de la requette
            console.log(response)
        },
      // on error
      error: function(response) { //sinon
          console.log("the error returned: %o", response)
      }
});
```

Note: the "Task" variable is a table of objects.

Hhere is the method responsible for storing the data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $i=0; $data = [];
    if(count($request->all()) != 0 ) {
        foreach ($request->all() as $task) {
            if(TaskSave::create($task)) {
                $i++;
            }
        }

        if($i == count($request->all())) {
            $data = [
                'success' => "Toutes les taches ont été sauvée"
            ];
        } else {
            $data = [
                'error' => "certaines données n'ont pas été sauvées"
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $data = [
            'error' => "Vous n'avez pas envoyé de données"
        ];
    }

    return response()->json( $data, 200);
}
```

and here's the return :

[image: screenshot of the request's ruturn]

Any hints on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you double checked what is actually sent by browser and compared with Postman request?

Comment: hello @phuzi, yes I copied the contents of the Tasks variable, and I submitted it to the API using Postman, and everything works there

Comment: Ok, buit did you check that what the browser sends is the same as what Postman sends? Check browser nettwork panel in dev tools and postman console

Comment: I see that in my browser, the "content-Type" Header has the value "text / html; charset = UTF-8" is it a problem ? beacause in Postman it is seted to "applicaytion/json"
if yes, how can i set the content-Type in Ajax  please?

Comment: is it possible that it's a problem of csrf-token ? because am not using a  form to post my data, it's just a collectection of object i created

Comment: Take a look at the `contentType` property on [jQuery.ajax options](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=version%20added%3A%201.5)-,contentType,-(default%3A%20%27application/x)

Comment: ok I take a look

Comment: I took a look, and it says this default is the recommended one.
however, it is not the one that PostMan uses, when I use these values ​​on Postman, no data is sent, even if I do not receive an error 500 as on the browser

Comment: should we continue on chat please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, that works for me:

```
$("#saver").on("click", event => {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(Tasks))
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // on précise la methode
        url: url_store, //l'url vers laquelle AJAX doit diriger la requette
        data: JSON.stringify(Tasks),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // async:false,
        // on success 
        success: function(response) { // si tout se passe bien NOTE: reponse contient la réponse obtenu de la requette
                alert(response.success)
            },
        // on error
        error: function(response) { //sinon
            console.log("the error returned: %o", response)
        }
    });
})
```

apparently, to be taken into account, the data must be changed to a string.
and then i also changed the contentType to "application/json; charset=utf-8".
this solution worked for me, hope it helps others.